# IOS custom progress bar with CAShapeLayer

Tags: ios, swift, view, progress

how can I create a custom bow like this picture with the text of the end of arc

[image: rainbow loading image]

this is my current code and current result

```
        let center = view.center
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 120, startAngle:  CGFloat.pi , endAngle: CGFloat.pi*2, clockwise: true)

        
        let greyLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        greyLayer.strokeColor = greyColor
        greyLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        greyLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        greyLayer.lineCap = .round
        greyLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        greyLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        greyLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        greyLayer.shadowOffset = .zero
        greyLayer.shadowRadius = 2
        view.layer.addSublayer(greyLayer)


        shapeLayer.strokeColor = bowColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd =  0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))

        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Best"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .red
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
        
                
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(label.layer)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive  = true
        
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
```

current result
I wanna add a circle shape to the end of the arc and animated like above picture,
I have no idea how to implement this
[image]

Comment: https://github.com/EranBoudjnah/MTCircularSlider/blob/master/MTCircularSlider/Classes/MTCircularSlider.swift

Answer (score 1):

To get you started...

Your arc goes from `.pi` to `.pi*2` ... but instead of `.pi*2` it may help you to think about it as:

- the arc starts at `.pi`, which is "9 o'clock"
- complete progress would span to "3 o'clock", which is **adding** `.pi` to the start angle

The completion progress would be `.pi` **plus** `.pi * progressPercent`.

So, to get the `endAngle`:

- 25% progress would be `.pi + ((25.0 / 100.0) * .pi)`
- 50% progress would be `.pi + ((50.0 / 100.0) * .pi)`
- 83% progress would be `.pi + ((83.0 / 100.0) * .pi)`

Coded, you would do something like this:

```
    let score = 83
    
    let endAngle: CGFloat = .pi + ((CGFloat(score) / 100.0) * .pi)
    
    let center = view.center
    let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 120, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)
```

Now you have your arc spanning 83% of the "half-circle."

To add a label at the end of the arc, you can get that point from the path:

```
    // point at end of arc
    let endPoint: CGPoint = circularPath.currentPoint
```

And you can use that point to position your label (or custom "balloon" label view).

Here's your code, slightly modified to add a `score` value and a `progressLabel`:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
        view.backgroundColor = .systemTeal
        
    }
    
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        
        let greyColor = UIColor.gray.cgColor
        let bowColor = UIColor.systemPink.cgColor
        let lineWidth: CGFloat = 12
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        
        let score = 83
        
        let endAngle: CGFloat = .pi + (.pi * (CGFloat(score) / 100.0))
        
        let center = view.center
        let circularPath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 120, startAngle: .pi, endAngle: endAngle, clockwise: true)

        // point at end of arc
        let endPoint: CGPoint = circularPath.currentPoint
        
        let greyLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        greyLayer.strokeColor = greyColor
        greyLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        greyLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        greyLayer.lineCap = .round
        greyLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        greyLayer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        greyLayer.shadowOpacity = 1
        greyLayer.shadowOffset = .zero
        greyLayer.shadowRadius = 2
        view.layer.addSublayer(greyLayer)
        
        
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = bowColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.path = circularPath.cgPath
        shapeLayer.lineCap = .round
        shapeLayer.strokeEnd =  0
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        view.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        //view.addGestureRecognizer(UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handleTap)))
        
        let label = UILabel()
        label.text = "Best"
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.textColor = .red
        label.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 30)
        
        
        view.addSubview(label)
        
        view.layer.addSublayer(label.layer)
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor).isActive = true
        
        label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive  = true
        
        label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor).isActive = true
        
        let progressLabel = UILabel()
        progressLabel.backgroundColor = .cyan
        progressLabel.text = "\(score)%"
        progressLabel.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(progressLabel)
        progressLabel.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: endPoint.y).isActive = true
        progressLabel.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: endPoint.x).isActive = true

    }
}
```

The result:

[image]

If you want to "animate" the progress arc and label, that will take some more work... but that's a good exercise in learning for you to take on.